# Антивирус блокирует мою java программу

Tags: java, windows, exe

Всем привет. У меня есть прога на java которая закачивает файлы с сервера и запускает их (лаунчер для игры)
Ее я компилю в jar и с помощью launc4j превращаю в exe. И вот этот exe антивирус видит как вирус. И даже если отключить антивирус и запустить прогу, то она не будет закачивать и устанавливать файлы, пока не запустишь ее от имени администратора. Как решить эту проблему???

П.С. антивирус который блочит ее это: ESET NOD32 Smart Security

Comment: добавьте ее в исключения антивируса

Comment: А куда она "закачивает" файлы? В этот каталог могут писать обычные пользователи?

Comment: Обращайтесь к вендору

Comment: Лаунчер ставится по умолчанию в "C:\Program Files (x86)\Launcher" (но пользователь по желанию может указать другой каталог)
И соответственно в эту же папку и закачиваются файлы. 
Еще важно отметить, что файлы будут закачиваться, только если запустить лаунчер от имени администратора.
Добавлять прогу в исключения антивируса не вариант, потому что пользователи я думаю не станут этого делать
Еще я вычитал про ЭЦП для программы. Может знаете как можно сделать ее бесплатно или очень дешево?